# Javascript Recursively Adding to the right spot

Tags: javascript, recursion

I can't get my `add_child` function to push into the right place. This is because my brain has problems with recursion. Could any kind soul lend a hand at figuring out what I need to do?

I believe I need to keep track of how deep in the array globally and then add the child like `self.data[key][i].push({...});` but I can't seem to get it it right.

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pg7k/)

Otherwise, here is me calling the function to add some nodes:

```
var m = new Map();
m.add(1);
m.add(2);
m.add(3);
m.add(4, 3);
m.add(5, 3);
m.add(6, 5);
m.add(7, 5);

console.log(m.data)
```

Example of what I'm trying to produce:

```
  [
      {
          node_id: 0,
          children: null
      },
      {
          node_id: 1,
          children: [
          {
              node_id: 2
              children: null
          },
          {
              node_id: 3
              children: [

          }
          ]
      },
 ]
```

This the my function caller:

```
var Map = function() {

    var self = this;
    this.data = [];

    this.add = function(node_id, parent_id) {

        if (typeof parent_id == 'number') {
            self.add_child(node_id, parent_id, self.data);
            return;
        }

        self.data.push({
            'node_id': node_id,
            'children': []
        });

        return true;
    }

    this.add_child = function(node_id, needle, haystack) {

        for (var key in haystack)
        {
            if (haystack[key].children.length != 0)
            {
                self.add_child(node_id, needle, haystack[key].children);
            }
            else
            {
                if (haystack[key].node_id == needle)
                {
                    //console.log("Searching for needle: " + needle)
                    //console.log("Found it in: " + key)

                    //console.log("The Actual Data:")
                    //console.log(self.data[key]);

                    self.data[key].children.push({
                        'node_id': node_id,
                        'children': []
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Note that in your terminating case (`if (haystack[key].node_id == needle)`), you are adding to `self.data[key]` instead of `haystack[key]`.

Comment: In javascript, it is not recommended to use a `for(var x in ...)` loop to iterate over arrays. Prefer using [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or a standard `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)`. [for..in loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) are best used for objects, and should have an [Object.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) test for each key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the else condition it should do the trick, not the most efficient thing in the world as you're going to be walking most of the tree, something like this is best done with a binary search tree e.g. red black tree

http://jsfiddle.net/vhqxk/

```
        for (var key in haystack)
        {
            if (haystack[key].children.length != 0)
            {
                self.add_child(node_id, needle, haystack[key].children);
            }

            if (haystack[key].node_id == needle)
            {                    
                haystack[key].children.push({
                    'node_id': node_id,
                    'children': []
                });
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are a wizard, I can't believe it!

Answer (score 1):

There was few errors, here is working code, just add_child function

```
this.add_child = function(node_id, needle, haystack) {
    if (!haystack) { return; }
    for (var key in haystack) {
        // you need to check if haystack[key].children is not undefined
        if (haystack[key].children && haystack[key].children.length != 0) {
            self.add_child(node_id, needle, haystack[key].children);
        } else {
            if (haystack[key].node_id == needle) {
                // initialize children if null
                if (!haystack[key].children) {
                    haystack[key].children = [];
                }
                // append to haystack
                haystack[key].children.push({
                    'node_id': node_id,
                    'children': []
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Tested with your data:

```
var data = [
      {
          node_id: 0,
          children: null
      },
      {
          node_id: 1,
          children: [
          {
              node_id: 2,
              children: null
          },
          {
              node_id: 3,
              children: []

          }
          ]
      },
 ];

var map = new Map();
map.add_child(10, 0, data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Thanks this is a good reply (+1). However, when I add_child I don't want to have to pass in the data variable so I picked the other question. I can use some of this error checking though :)